# Maven current project compiled with java 1.6 which has 2 dependencies on java 1.7 and 1.6

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

My current Maven project is compiled with 1.6

```
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
```

However, it has 2 dependencies - say dep1.7 one of which is compiled with 1.7 and the other one, say dep1.6 is compiled with 1.6. Both dependencies cannot change their versions, i.e 1.7 dependency cannot be compiled with 1.6 and vice versa. 
Is there a way out of this one?
I can upgrade my application to compile with java 1.7.
Right now, my unit tests which use the dep1.7 fails with a Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 as expected.

Comment: Besides upgrading to Java 1.7, there's no way to fix this.  But honestly, what did you expect when you decided to use an older version of Java with libraries compiled against a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

How about compiling dep1.6 with Java 7. It should be doable since it should be forward compatible unless I am missing something.

Comment: how do we do it? its a third party jar - don't think we can do it.